# Drop down menu reduce global variable scope

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How can the global "x" variable be reduced in scope to local variable?
Please note that simply moving the "var x" inside the "showAddress" function will not work as the keyup event listener will reset the variable to 0 evetytime. Any help is appreciated.

```
document.getElementById("where").addEventListener("keyup", showAddress, false);

var x = 0;

function showAddress (e) {

    var search = document.getElementById("where").value;
    if (search.length < 2) {
        document.getElementById("addressNav").innerHTML = '';
        return 0;
    } else {
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "/handlers/suggestAddress.php";
        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("addressNav").innerHTML = hr.responseText;


                // click on the address
                var divs = document.getElementById("addressNav").getElementsByTagName("div"), i;
                for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                    divs[i].onclick = function () {
                        document.getElementById("where").value = this.innerHTML;
                        document.getElementById("addressNav").innerHTML = '';
                    };
                }

                //navigate address from keyboard
                if (e.keyCode == 38) {
                    if (x > 0) {
                        x -= 1;
                    } else {
                        x = divs.length - 1;
                    }
                } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                    if (x < divs.length - 1) {
                        x += 1;
                    } else {
                        x = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        document.getElementById("where").value = divs[x].innerHTML;
                        document.getElementById("addressNav").innerHTML = '';
                    }
                }

                divs[x].setAttribute("class", "addressListKeyboard");
                console.log(x);
            }
        };
        hr.send("search=" + search);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is the issue/question that you are trying to ask here?

Comment: "var x" is currently declared as global and the code works, however is it only used in the "showAddress" function so I'd like to reduce the "var x" scope from global to local.

Comment: why the -1 ????

Comment: No worries, I will upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Variable x should remember the last selected div and that's why it has global scope. Moving it to local scope will not work as showAddress is keyup event handler which will erase the value of x each time the keyup event occurs.

Comment: I had tried that but it does not work as the "var x" is reset every keyup event, hence it is declared as global.

Comment: Ahhh! How did I missed that. You are right Swartz. Variable x should remember the last selected div. I have updated my answer with this. I will come up with other solution.